# PostgreSQL 8.3 - issues with autovacuum

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to encourage the use and monitoring of autovacuum in some PostgreSQL 8.3 databases.

One objection I hit often is that people don't "trust" autovacuum or there are bugs in autovacuum in 8.3 which mean that it's ignored in preference to scheduling vacuuming.  Mostly our tables are small and this approach appears to work.  However, with our larger (& also heavily updated tables) this really doesn't work (dead tuple counts increase, exceed max_fsm_pages, and the tables don't get cleaned up etc etc).

I'm just wondering if anyone has a reference for autovacuum in 8.3 being buggy or not working.  My own experience has shown that autovac works fine and, where necessary, adding entries to the pg_autovacuum table does the trick but I'm not having any luck convincing anyone else.

I'd like to understand the problem with autovacuum (if one exists).

Thanks

Comment: Probably better suited for http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks.  I have posted to dba.stackexchange.

Comment: Ask this question to the people that don't trust autovacuum: They can you why they don't trust it and what bugs they encounter. If there are any bugs or other problems...

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6158/postgresql-8-3-issues-with-autovacuum - there are answers here.  Frank - in principle I agree with you but that approach doesn't always work!